# C# Making a Discord bot cant figure a way to make cooldown

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to make a cool down in between commands to stop the program from being spammed, I cant figure out how to do this. In theory this should work, at least from my point of view, if anyone has an answer to this or a better way to do it, I would appreciate it.

```
if (message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))
{
    var cooldownSet = DateTime.Now;

    if ((DateTime.Now - cooldownSet).Seconds >= 1)
    {
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

        var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);

        if (!result.IsSuccess)
            Console.WriteLine("{" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "} - " + result.ErrorReason);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a timer be better suited? Also maybe incorporate threading?

Comment: Um. On every 'command' you basically are doing `(DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now).Seconds`.

Comment: Well your code sets the `cooldownSet` value and then immediately checks if was more than a second ago, which is obviously never going to be true. So this method will always return having done nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are obviously inside an async method, you could use [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) to wait for certain amount of time, and then execute the command.

```
if (message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos)) {

    // will delay for 1 second
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

    var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);

    if (!result.IsSuccess)
        Console.WriteLine("{" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "} - " + result.ErrorReason);
}
```